# Does Quip have a document search API?

Tags: api, quip

I've looked high and low in the Quip docs to see if there's a way to search Quip documents via an API. Does anyone know of such an endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you have probably already found this by now, but if not there is the quip automation api which does include a basic search ability: https://igt.quip.com/dev/automation/documentation#search-for-threads
For a more robust search, you would need to write a script to loop through every thread